# SAML-P to WS-Trust / WS-Fed Transition?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, ws-federation, ws-trust

Is anyone aware of the possible options besides ADFS for federating between an Idp that uses SAML-P (SAML 2.0 Asserts) and a replying party that uses WS-Fed / WS-Trust (SAML 1.1 Assertions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. PingFederate from Ping Identity supports all those things. We have several supported use cases where we can "route" between protocol/versions and Passive/Active. We also added Oauthv2 support in our latest release. [Note: I work for Ping].

Check out the Product site for more info - [PingFederate Product Info](https://www.pingidentity.com/our-solutions/pingfederate.cfm)

HTH
Ian

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have any white papers / guides / documentation on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific docs that have been written to help you accomplish this. However, I would suggest that you talk with our Sales Team who can help you with your technical evaluation, assist in defining the use cases you need to meet and discuss how PingFederate would need to be configured to best meet your needs.